# Sequentially replace characters in textbox animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've successfully been able to loop through a long string of characters in a textbox and replace them sequentially one by one with values randomly picked from an array.

My issue is getting the timing correct. I want to be able to complete the animation in X seconds regardless of the string length, that is if the animation should take 2 seconds it should take 2 seconds regardless if the string is 10 characters long or 300. I think my math may just be off because it takes much longer than 2 seconds to complete the animation.

It's probably easier to explain with the fiddle that I have. [> Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheMuffinMan/L3w5g22a/1/)

My loop looks something like:

```
var totalSeconds = 1000;
var stringLen = 100
setInterval(function(){
 ...
}, totalSeconds/(stringLen*1000));
```

Aside from the timing issue, is there a better approach than what I have and/or is there a library that I can use to achieve the same result?

I saw http://jschr.github.io/textillate/ but couldn't figure out how to implement the character replacement into it. (Looks like it just does animation out of the box).

Comment: Looks like the minimum delay is 4ms.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to rely on setInterval because of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval (

> "delay is the number of milliseconds (thousandths of a second) that the setInterval() function should wait before each call to func. As with setTimeout, there is a minimum delay enforced.

Instead, you probably want a loop that detects how much time has passed between each iteration.

```
var interval = totalSeconds*1000/(stringLen)
var totalCount = 0;
var prev = new Date().getTime();

while(totalCount < stringLen) {
  var current = new Date().getTime();
  var passed = current - prev;
  prev = current;

 // passed is how much time has passed between intervals
 var count = passed / interval;
  for (var i =0; i< count; i++) {
    // change letter here...
  }
  totalCount += count;

  // Carry over remainder
  prev -= passed % interval;
}
```

This is untested :)